# Old iMessages and text messages have all disappeared after iOS 10 update?

Tags: iphone, ios

When I opened my Messages app after updating to iOS 10, my entire history of text messages was gone. I thought maybe they would return after leaving the phone plugged in and connected to wifi but this isn't the case.
Where'd they all go? Literally years of conversations have disappeared - I didn't think this was a problem at first but I hadn't realized how much I relied on old text messages for stuff.

Comment: Did you make a backup before updating?